# Erasing/Clipping Buffer layer at 90 degrees based on overlayed polygons QGIS3.0

Tags: qgis-3

My picture shows the basic idea of what I am needing to accomplish.

I can't find any tools that will do this.

It takes a buffer layer and chops out the pieces of it, at 90 degree angle to the buffer sides, for those areas not "infected" by the overlaid polygons.

So, the resulting polygon layer will have singlepart polygons of the areas that were "infected" along the buffer path.

It is critical that the resulting polygons are the same width as the original buffer, which is why a simple erase won't work.

So even though there may only be a small splotch of a polygon overlaid on the buffer, an entire slice of the buffer must be kept to preserve the area that was "infected".

[image]

Comment: Try to search along the line of rotated minimum bounding rectangle. Then you could subtract.

Comment: This sounds like oriented bounding boxes? I tried that tool but the boxes don't always make it all the way across the buffer width and I don't know of a way to make them. Perhaps the geometry by expression could do it but seems like it would be complicated.

Comment: @bkg73123 Do you still have the line layer you used for light green buffer? Since one of the two-sides of green buffer is lost at around the kink, it will be hard to build 90-degrees constraint there. I think it will be easier if we start working with the center-line.

Comment: Yes I do still have the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Step 1) Create Transect lines from the center line.

[image]

1. Densify the center line. `Vector geometry | Densify by interval`
2. Create transect. `Vector geometry | Transect` (set Length same as the buffer size, select `Both` sides).

(Step 2) Extract transect lines which intersect with splotches

[image]

1. `Vector selection | Extract by location`

(Step 3) Create minimum bounded geometry which enclose selected lines

[image]

1. Copy id field of the splotch polygons to the selected transect lines.
2. Create polygons by `Vector geometry | Minimum bounding geometry` (I chose Convex hull, but you may prefer Minimum oriented rectangle).

Comment: I can't seem to get past the first step. I run the Densify by Interval tool on the centerline and the result is a blank layer with no features. Can't figure out why.

Comment: @bkg73123 How about skipping `Densify` step and start from `Transect`? If your line is smooth and has enough nodes, it is not necessary to have more nodes.

Comment: Same thing. When I run Densify by Interval or Transect on the centerline layer the result is a blank layer with no features. I don't get any errors. I even tried creating a new layer and drawing a new line worth same results.

Comment: I think I am on the right track by using Densify by Count. It seems to work. Then the Transect works as well just trying to get the lengths correct.

Comment: @bkg73123 This [bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18640) report may be related. Is it QGIS 3.0 Girona? I am in QGIS 3.2 if it makes changes...

Comment: Yes 3.0 Girona. I will try upgrading. Right now I got through the first three steps as I mentioned. Getti g side tracked trying to see if I can use the transect lines layer to split the buffer into segments and then extract those segments so I won't need to mess with the bounding boxes. No luck yet.

Comment: @bkg73123 That's brilliant idea. To cut polygon by line, `SAGA | Vector polygon tools | Polygon-line intersection` tool may help.

Comment: That tool was brutal to the buffer layer. I am so close with the native split by lines tool. After splitting have to do multipart to singlepart but then can't seem to get extract by location to just select the individual buffer segments, keeps wanting to select entire buffer.

Comment: The oriented minimum bounding box doesn't close the gaps for me, but the regular bounding boxes did worke on simple example. Then I dissolved the bounding boxes to clean it up. Will try with more complicated line.

Comment: I found the best results,though not perfect, is taking the extracted transect lines and buffering them till they just overlap then dissolving them. This has issues with curves. If anyone can figure out how to buffer a line that doesn't dissolve the curves but instead overlaps the buffer on top of itself on tight curves, I think there is a better chance of getting this working with splitting the buffer with the transect lines. Then there is still the issue of selecting the buffer segments. That would be the most accurate solution I can think of right now. Thank you Kazuhito!